# Google analytics integration with Java api

Tags: spring, api, google-analytics

I want to integrate google analytics with my Spring boot API.
Whenever I send an event request, I always get forbidden in google analytics response.
the request I'm using is

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?api_secret={API_SECRET}&measurement_id={MEASUREMENT_ID}
```

with a payload of:

```
{
  "client_id": "{CLIENT_ID}",
  "timestamp_micros": "1652351615578000",
  "non_personalized_ads": false,
  "events": [
      {
          "name": "test"
      }
  ]
}
```

I got the API_SECRET and MEASUREMENT_ID from analytics webpage
and the CLIENT_ID in the payload from google analytics javascript library
I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct endpoint for the [google analytics measurement protocol ga4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag) is

> https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect

You are using

HTTP.